# Where to get N'SIQ for C#?

Tags: c#, hudson, jenkins, cyclomatic-complexity

The latest official release of [N'SIQ Code Metric Collector](http://dev.naver.com/projects/nsiqcollector) (2.1.4 built in 2010-03-31) doesn't support C#. But there are [evidences](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins/nsiqcollector/1.3.2/hudson/plugins/nsiq/model/FileType.java) in the internet that someone is using the NSIQ Collector Plugin for [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/NSIQ+Collector+Plugin) and [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NSIQ+Collector+Plugin) with unsupported languages like C# and Objective C. Where can I find N'SIQ builds that support C#, even if it is an unofficial build?

Comment: If you are running on Windows, you might want to try [Microsoft Visual Studio Code Metrics Power Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9422).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on Windows, you might want to try [Microsoft Visual Studio Code Metrics Power Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9422).